# Array help needed - Coding errors

Tags: java, arrays

I need to implement a method that takes an array called applicants, and two instances from a seperate class called Person, and prints out names of those applicants whose age is between 22 and 30 inclusive. The class Person has methods getName() and getAge() that return the name and the age of the applicant. In other words, the class Person is declared as follows:

```
public class Person{
public String getName(String name) {
return name; 
 }
public int getAge(int age){
return age;
 }
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
public class Applicants
{
public static void main(String args[]){
String [] name = new String[8];
name[0] = "Student A";
name[1] = "Student B";
name[2] = "Student C";
name[3] = "Student D";
name[4] = "Student E";
name[5] = "Student F";
name[6] = "Student G";
name[7] = "Student H";

int [] age = new int[8];
age[0] = 21;
age[1] = 28;
age[2] = 16;
age[3] = 23;
age[4] = 22;
age[5] = 28;
age[6] = 22;
age[7] = 21;

}

public static void printSelection(Person applicants[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < applicants.length; i++)
    if (22 <= applicants[i].getAge() && applicants[i].getAge() <= 30)
    System.out.println(applicants[i].getName()); 
 }

}
```

I know I have not prepared an array called applicants (yet). I am not sure how I can basically take these two arrays called names and ages and make the one array called applicants?
Or do I just convert the array names to applicants? 
This is a class session so please forgive my errors. I just need to learn how a professional would do this sort of thing so that I may learn from it and move on.

The final output is required to print out the applicant name and age that is between 22 and 30. The getName and getAge must be called from a separate class as shown below.

Comment: The `getName` and `getAge` methods seem redundant. They return the same what they are passed. Is this intended?

Comment: Since this looks like homework, I'll just give you hints: 1) You have a `Person` class that can contain `name` and `age`, but you're not using it. 2) You may have two arrays of `String[] name` and `int[] age`, use them to create a `Person[] applicant` array. 3) Use the `applicant` data to solve your problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. I am not sure of the point of these return types. What are they supposed to do?

Comment: As someone trying to learn Java, why are questions down voted? In this particular case my question has -2 at the moment.
Is this because it is deemed as a stupid question? Or is just poor in general?
This is not a moan, its just a genuine question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there is no need for two arrays. You can simply create object instances of type Person.

```
public class Person{
    public String getName(String name) {
        // Why would the user pass a value they want returned right back to them?
        return name; 
    }
    public int getAge(int age){
        // Same here as well. This needs to be addressed!
        return age;
    }
 }
```

Firstly this code will not work. There is no field name and field age in the class. That is your first problem to solve. You also need to make a constructor for this class, that takes name and age as a parameter, and binds them to the fields you have defined. ie:

```
public Person(int age, String name)
{
     this.age = age;
     this.name = name;
}
```

The next step would be to add the values to a person object, then adding that person object to a collection(like an array, or arraylist). In your main method, you might have something like..

```
Person[] applicants = new Person[8];
```

Now you should add new instances of the Person object to this collection, with the relevant data.

Pass this array to your function and you will print out the selected values.

Comment: It's not like I've just given him the code. I've explained all the details in the middle. All the same, I'll edit out some of it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No its fine. This is pointing me in the right direction. I can see now. I just need this sort of thing so I can see what it does.

Comment: @ChrisCooney Many thanks for your guidance. This is a good learning curve for me.
Thank you both.

Comment: Well i've done it now and I like my answer more, so it's staying. Your suggestion was quite right; I shouldn't have given away so much.

Comment: @PrimalScientist It was my pleasure. Be sure to mark this as the correct answer for future readers. :)

Comment: Please next time refer to [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/182862), section *Answering and moderating homework questions*, second point. I don't downvote this because the 4th point in that section.